# How to indicate changes in the preview of a grid

Tags: user-behavior, preview

I have a web page that allows a user user to preview the changes they made.

The page has a grid with data and the user can edit each row. In the preview, the user wants to see what he/she has changed.

Something like this grid http://www.jeasyui.com/demo/main/index.php

So I need to implement some kind of preview that show the differences. For example underlining deleted content with red, or new content with green etc.

I've searched the web for this problem but I didn't manage to find anything on the best practice about it.

Where can I read about user experience best practices related to creating a preview page with the ability to emphasize changes that were made by the user (where the user will be able to check what things they've changed, deleted or added)?

Comment: You could show the grid as usual and highlight every new entry green,deleted entried red and changed entried as yellow. You can look ok how stackexchange.com, github.com or wikipedia.org handle it. You could edit your Question and then press on this "Edited X minutes ago".

Comment: And if i have 5 pages with 20 rows per each page? Will it be ok for user to go thought all pages in order to see what was changed?

Comment: Maybe you could show them at the very beginnling something like "X entries deleted ; Y entried created ; Z entried modifies". Just so the user can see if it's at least barely correct.

Comment: Also you can hide most of the document in most cases. If i only add a single entry at like 200 then i might just show him line 195-205 and tell him "Hidden Lines 1-199" so he doesnt need to scroll throu his entire document if he made on my minor changes

Comment: @user207607: As a general solution, you can indicate which pages contain changes, or you put it on one page, let the user scroll and use a color-coded navbar / scrollbar to find changes.  But **why** a user needs to see / review changes: what drives them, why would they spend the time?  Your solution depends on that.

Answer (score 0):

There are existing design patterns that address this issue for applications that compare the difference between two documents, and you can apply these to the data in a grid as well, which is actually a lot easier because the layout of the content is simpler. I won't put links to tools here but you can search them using keywords like text comparison or diff tools.

What you need to do is provide indicators (i.e. combination of text, icon and colour) to show what has been added, removed or modified to the original view and also the preview (ideally side-by-side). Obviously the original view won't have anything that is added, while the preview won't have anything that is removed, and both views will share what is modified.

If you want to show everything in just the preview, it is a little bit more difficult but you can use strikethrough styling for removed items. But this can be difficult to follow visually if there are large sections or many deletions.